# Coldfusion Query to Object Tree

Tags: coldfusion

I need to convert an SQL Query to a nasty object tree.

Basically I need to have this kind of tree

```
[
    id_record,
    mSap,
    process_rev,
    process: [
        {
            mpProcess,
            mpOrder,
            bom: [
                {
                    mbItem,
                    mbQuantity,
                    mbYield,
                    alt: [
                        {
                            maFatherItem,
                            maAltItem
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

This is the query result [in JSON format.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/146e993a9a196fcc1c80c3c4cf9f3637) that I needed to convert. I think I can do this in ES6 Javascript but I need it using Coldfusion. 
I can read PHP too so maybe I can just convert it to Coldfusion.
Its too complex, I don't know how to make it.

This is the query for everyone that is asking:

```
SELECT a.id_record, a.mSap, 
       b.process_rev, b.mpOrder, b.mpProcess, b.bom_rev, b.mbITem, b.mbQuantity, b.mbYield,  b.maFatherItem, b.maAltItem 
  FROM tbl_model a 
  LEFT JOIN ( 
     SELECT c.mpModel AS model, d.process_rev, c.mpOrder, c.mpProcess, e.bom_rev, e.mbItem, e.mbQuantity, e.mbYield, e.maFatherItem, e.maAltItem   
       FROM tbl_model_process c 
      INNER JOIN ( 
          SELECT mrModel, MAX(mrRevision) AS process_rev 
            FROM tbl_model_revision 
           WHERE mrApproved = 2 
             AND mrType = 0 
             AND mrActive = 1 
           GROUP BY mrModel
            ) d 
              ON c.mpRevision = d.process_rev 
             AND c.mpModel = d.mrModel 
         LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT f.mbModel, f.mbRevision AS bom_rev, f.mbProcess, f.mbItem, f.mbQuantity, f.mbYield, h.maFatherItem, h.maAltItem 
              FROM tbl_model_bom f 
             INNER JOIN ( 
                 SELECT mrModel, MAX(mrRevision) AS bom_rev 
                   FROM tbl_model_revision 
                  WHERE mrApproved = 2 
                    AND mrType = 1 
                    AND mrActive = 1
                  GROUP BY mrModel
                  ) g 
                    ON f.mbModel = g.mrModel 
                   AND f.mbRevision = g.bom_rev 
               LEFT JOIN ( 
                  SELECT maModel, maProcess, maRevision, maFatherItem, maAltItem
                    FROM tbl_model_alt
                    ) h 
                      ON f.mbModel = h.maModel 
                     AND f.mbProcess = h.maProcess 
                     AND f.mbItem = h.maFatherItem 
                     AND f.mbRevision = h.maRevision
          ) e 
            ON c.mpModel = e.mbModel 
           AND c.mpProcess = e.mbProcess 
    ) b 
   ON b.model = a.id_record 
WHERE a.mActive = 1 
  AND a.mSap IN (:models) 
ORDER BY a.id_record, b.process_rev, b.mpOrder, b.mpProcess
```

Comment: It will be less complex if you do one thing at a time.

Comment: What does the query data look like? What have you tried so far and what was the result?

Comment: @DanBracuk It will slow down the system if I do it one at a time. Also, I still need to have the whole data saved in a single variable because of Cfwheels and API application things,

Comment: @Ageax I added my query above.

Comment: @KaySingian - Can you post a sanitized sample of the raw query results (not in JSON format)?

Comment: Put a maxrows attribute on your query so that you are working with a manageable amount of data.  Try the suggestions in the two answers that have been posted so far.

Comment: What database are you using? That query looks like it may be doing a bit of extra work. If you can simplify your query, it may help you see how to get the data in a way that you need.

Comment: @shawn This is just MySQL. Actually this is very complex because I still need to look up for the name of the IDs of the models or material, and those names are saved in Microsoft SQL Server. The code above is the simplest I can think of, and is so much faster than splitting up into multiple queries. Basically, I have to get the model, then the revision number of the process, the revision number of the bom, then the processes, then the boms of the processes, and then the alternatives of the boms. Just a deeply nested project. I think I figured out how to create nested tree objects now.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of cf you are using, group your query by process, bom, alt and then use group attribute of cfoutput or cf10+ loop and build up your json output.

Comment: Not the best answer, but upvoted to get the reputation high enough to make comments.

Answer (score 0):

Is the query a ColdFusion variable?  Can you simply send it to serializeJSON()?

```
<cfquery datasource="dsn" name="qry">
SELECT * FROM table
</cfquery>
<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(qry)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Is this Stack Overflow or Jeapordy?

Comment: @PMascari - Total guess, since there's no code or sample data in the OP, but it sounds like they do have a query variable, but the data isn't in the right format for a straight serializeJSON() to work.